# Create windows service with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, windows-services

I got some problem with windows service.

I create a service project and Install it to Windows Service and start it, I got no error, but when I try to place this code `this.masterQuery = new MasterQuery(this.entities);`, I got the error from Services when I start it.

`error 1053 the service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion`

how can I solve this? I need the entity to use at the services.

Comment: That error is nothing to do with EF, but that Window's service control manager is not getting responses from the service. Try getting a "does nothing" service running first.

Comment: how to fix the Window's service to getting the response? @Richard

Comment: Depends why it isn't responding. Without seeing the implementation I can only guess. I would think you're probably doing too much in the startup code before handle control to the SCM.

Comment: If the service starts normal without this line of code then it may be a timeout of EF. Perhaps the service cannot connect to the database. Check the connectionstring. Are you using integrated security? This will not work for a service. You can use sql login instead.